# Jenkins CVS plugin does not detect changes

Tags: jenkins, cvs, jenkins-plugins

We've been running Jenkins 1.451 and 1.454 on Windows XP against a CVS repository for a few weeks now, without any problems. The CVS plugin (v1.6) was using the local cvsnt install.

We've since upgraded the CVS plugin to version 2.1 this morning and since then, CVS changes are not detected. The CVS polling log is triggered properly, tons of "cvs rlog" instructions are sent but at the end "No changes" is displayed.

Am I missing some configuration option somewhere?

Thanks.

**Update 1**: Looking into the entries file, I'm seeing incorrect times for recently updated files, the entry being 4 hours later than the actual change. Could this be related? I'm in the Eastern Time Zone (Montreal) with Daylight Saving Time in effect. The last cvs checkout command looked like this:

cvs checkout -P -r d-chg00014229_op_brc_preimp-op-2012-02-27 -D 23 Mar 2012 11:56:16 EDT -d portailInt portailInt

**Update 2**: The 4 hour difference corresponds to GMT-adjusted time, so it looks like there's a mixup in time zones somewhere. Using CVS plugin 1.6 the cvs polling command looked like this (executed at 5:26:21 PM EDT):

cvs -q -z3 -n update -PdC -r d-chg00014229_op_brc_preimp-op-2012-02-27 -D "Thursday, March 22, 2012 9:26:21 PM UTC"

Is it possible that the CVS server isn't properly interpreting the -D argument, either the parsing part or the time zone adjustment part?

**Update 3**: Behaviour is the same with CVS plugin 2.2

**Update 4**: Manual calls to "cvs rlog" do not return anything, while similar calls to "cvs log" return revision information for all module files.

```
cvs rlog -d"01 Mar 2012 09:26:21 -0400<27 Mar 2012 12:00:00 -0400" -S -rd-chg00014229_op_brc_preimp-op-2012-02-27 portailInt
cvs rlog: Logging portailInt

cvs log -d"01 Mar 2012 09:00:00 -0400<27 Mar 2012 12:00:00 -0400"
RCS file: /usr/local/cvs/repcvs/PortailInternetMouvement/portailInt/Portail/src/com/xxx/pvm/portail/taglib/I18nBundleTag.java,v
Working file: Portail/src/com/xxx/pvm/portail/taglib/I18nBundleTag.java
head: 1.3
branch:
locks: strict
access list:
symbolic names:
d-chg00014229_op_impl_2012-03-25_v06: 1.1.2.4
d-chg00014229_op_impl_2012-03-25_v05: 1.1.2.4
aq_op_2012-03-25_v04: 1.1.2.4
d-chg00014229_op_impl_2012-03-25_v04: 1.1.2.4
aq_op_2012-03-25_v03: 1.1.2.3
d-chg00014229_op_impl_2012-03-25_v03: 1.1.2.3
d-chg00014229_op_impl_2012-03-25_v02: 1.1.2.3
aq_op_2012-03-25_v01: 1.1
d-chg00014229_op_impl_2012-03-25_v01: 1.1
d-chg00014229_op_brc_preimp-op-2012-02-27: 1.1.0.2
preimp_op_2012-02-27: 1.1
keyword substitution: kv
total revisions: 8; selected revisions: 3
description:
----------------------------
revision 1.1.2.5
date: 2012/03/23 15:42:50; author: ba0chzi; state: Exp; lines: +4 -26
Organize imports
----------------------------
revision 1.1.2.4
date: 2012/03/13 14:18:27; author: ba0chmn; state: Exp; lines: +1 -1
Changement de scope de request ou session pour application dans le but d'améliorer les performances
----------------------------
revision 1.1.2.3
date: 2012/03/06 21:19:03; author: ba0chmn; state: Exp; lines: +14 -8
Utilisation des services de récupération de fichier dans UCM de xxx
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is exactly, but I noticed that it does some to pick up changes for us from HEAD. However, for tag and branch, we don't see changes. I'm adding this to the bug you opened (thanks for doing that, btw)

Comment: Happy to see this isn't an isolated case. Are you using version 2.x too?

Comment: Yep. Had to upgrade because it uses rlog, and that allows files in the workspace to be ignored when checking for changes (otherwise we'd get builds even without changes).

Comment: I see. I think I've narrowed it down to the behaviour of the "cvs rlog" command, which isn't working as I would expect against a branch.

Comment: I've been going through the CVS man page to see if I can find anything that would cause this not to work (the way it is printed on the console). Does not seem like anything particularly wrong...

Comment: I've posted this as a separate, CVS-focused question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909805/cvs-rlog-not-working-as-expected-against-a-branch

Comment: Running the same command without the -S switch produces the output that I would expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a bug. Documented here: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-13227