# cvs rlog not working as expected against a branch

Tags: cvs

Version info:
Client: Concurrent Versions System (CVSNT) 2.0.4 (client/server)
Server: Concurrent Versions System (CVS) 1.11.22-FCDQ_LEGO-2.2 (client/server)

The "portailInt" module is stored on the CVS repository.  Branch "d-chg00014229_op_brc_preimp-op-2012-02-27" was created on February 27th 2012 and many changes have been committed to this branch since then.

When running the following command:
cvs rlog -S -rd-chg00014229_op_brc_preimp-op-2012-02-27 -d"01 Mar 2012 00:00:00 -0400 < 31 Mar 2012 00:00:00 -0400" portailInt

I receive the following output:
cvs rlog: Logging portailInt

I was expecting to see logs for all files changed between March 1st and March 31st for this module's branch.  Why am I not seeing this?

Thanks a bunch.

**Update**: Removing the -S switch seems to show a lot more output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the -S switch is showing the expected output.